# Resolving pkg-config to packages

Tags: dpkg, pkg-config

I'm trying to build something from source, and the configure tells me something like this:

```
checking for foo... Package foo was not found in the pkg-config search path.
```

So I have to go and install the development package for foo (or whatever). Normally this is called `libfoo-dev`, but not always.

Is there some easy way of looking up the name of the dpkg package for a given pkg-config package?

Comment: `apt-file` might help. There is also [Ubuntu packages](http://packages.ubuntu.com) and using a graphical package manager like Synaptic or Muon.